# In a .NET Core 3.1 WPF desktop app calling IPublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(...WithPrompt, can a custom popup be created?

Tags: .net-core, azure-ad-msal

When I call IPublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive() it always seems to open a browser to display the SelectAccount workflow.

Isn't there a way for the interactive SelectAccount to display as a PopUp rather than in a browser? I can't find any code to demonstate that but I suspect it can be done